# Text to Columns in Excel Split date and time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a small issue. I need to split the date and time within one cell. Normally I would do a text to columns and use delimited by space. But that issue is the AM and PM is put into it's own column. What I am trying to do is split out the date and have the time connected to the AM or PM in the same column as shown in the image below. Want to produce Column T and U.
I want the 5:00:00AM to look like that where the AM is attached to the last number

[image]

Comment: Double-click the little arrow on top of the vertical line separating AM/PM into its own column. Alternately, Drag it out of the little text window.

Answer (score 3):

In **T2** enter:

```
=INT(N2)
```

In **U2** enter:

```
=N2-T2
```

Then apply appropriate format to the cells.

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To remove the space before the *AM / PM*, use a custom format:

[image]

Comment: But I wanted the AM to be right next to the 00 at the end of you.. Look like this  5:00:00AM

Comment: @ArnoldB  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 3):

Use Text-to-Columns, Fixed width. Double-click the little arrow on top of the vertical line separating AM/PM into its own column. Alternately, Drag it out of the little text window. This removes it and combines the second and third column.

[image]